# Color swatches on category page?

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to add color swatches on category page.

I have this code in functions.php :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'sm_display_product_color_options', 9 );
function sm_display_product_color_options(){
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    $variation_colors_data = $product->get_attributes();
    $variation_colors_data = $variation_colors_data['pa_color'];
    $variation_colors = $variation_colors_data['options'];
    echo "<div class='product_colors_container'>";
    foreach ($variation_colors as $variation_color) {
        echo "<div class='variable-item-span variable-item-span-color' style='background-color:".get_term_meta($variation_color,'color',true)."'></div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

and this is the output:

```
<div class="product_colors_container"><div class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-color" style="background-color:"></div><div class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-color" style="background-color:"></div></div>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks.

Andrei

Comment: Try this free WooCommerce Variation Swatches plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-variation-swatches/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'sm_display_product_color_options', 9 );
function sm_display_product_color_options(){

    global $woocommerce, $product;
    $variation_colors_data = $product->get_attributes();

    $variation_colors_data = $variation_colors_data['color'];
    $variation_colors = $variation_colors_data['options'];


    echo "<div class='product_colors_container'>";
    foreach ($variation_colors as $variation_color) {
        echo "<div class='variable-item-span variable-item-span-color' style='background-color:".$variation_color."'>".$variation_color."</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Review below screenshot
[image]

Comment: Not working. If i use "color" instead of "pa_color" the output is: <div class="product_colors_container">

Comment: You have to create the attribute is "Color" right? it's assign as pa_color. So please change pa_color to color

Comment: The attribute is already there, the website is live, the attribute slug is "color" however it seems that is working with "pa_color" i guess is woocommerce default. I'm using a plugin  for swatches, but that is only showing them on product page. Now I want to show them on Shop/Category page as well.